# change image background size in zoom plugin dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins

- am using **jquery.elevatezoom** from [elevatezoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom).
- i written code for zooming images and am using base64 conversion getting from server.
- my code is : **HTML**
- `'<'label  id="lblImages" >Image :'<'/label>
  '<'div id="images" style="width:60px; height:60px;display: inline-block; border-style:solid; ">'<'/div>`
- my **javascript** code i.e. response callback function is:

  `var ImageStrSnap = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+response.Data.Images;//here base64 img string
  var images = new Image();
  images.src = ImageStrSnap;
  images.id = "snapImage";
  $('#images').html(images);

  $('#images img').css("height","60px");
  $('#images img').css("width","60px");
  $('#snapImage').attr('data-zoom-image', ImageStrSnap);

  //  $('.zoomWindow').css('background-size','460px 460px'); //not worked
  $('#snapImage').elevateZoom({zoomWindowPosition: 5,zoomWindowOffetx: 10});
  //  $('.zoomWindow').css('background-size','460px 460px');`//not worked
- i got problem is when i mouse over opening window container with width 400px & image is showing only in half screen.
- from server i got image size 144px 176px (if image changed to 460px 460px its worked same as in demo).
- any help or any suggestion for plugins.
- its working image as : [image: image 460px 460px]
- its working image as : [image: image 284px 177px]
- how to work same as 1st one for all size of images.